# Computational geometry algorithm which can deal with conic arc segments

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I've just finished reading a book named "Computational Geometry Algorithms and Applications". The algorithm introduced in this book is very helpfull for my future work.

But algorithm in this book only concerned about straight line segments. what i want to known is the same algorithm that can deal with both straight lines and conic arcs.

Such as find intersections of mixed line segments and conic arcs; offset polygon with conic arcs; find convex hull of concave polygon with conic arc edge...

3rd party libs, like CGAL can deal with problems like this, but i want to known the details of the algorithm. what's book or materials should i refer to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, computational geometry with curved arcs is more complicated and less explored.  But not unexplored, and often similar techniques suffice.  One place to look is CGAL, as you know; and LEDA, especially [here](http://www.quappa.com/tech-geom.htm#arcs):

[image: LEDA curved geom]

---

(*Added*): In response to the request for literature references, you could start with the paper below, and search backward in time via its references, and forward in time via Google Scholar (which reports it is cited by 79 papers):

> Eric Berberich, Arno Eigenwillig, Michael Hemmer, Susan Hert, Kurt Mehlhorn, Elmar Schömer
>   "A Computational Basis for Conic Arcs and Boolean Operations on Conic Polygons."
>   Lecture Notes in Computer Science Volume 2461, 2002, pp 174-186.
>   ([Springer link](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-45749-6_19?LI=true))

Comment: Well, thanks. But i am not searching for 3rd party library, but books or materials that describle such algorithm, like text-books or papers.